# htaccess working mechanism

Tags: php, .htaccess, function, redirect

**I have the folowing htaccess file:**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)-(.*)$   index.php?page=$1&id=$2&im=$3
```

**And inside the php page I have:**

href="home-46-126" //Contact Us

href="home-38-129" //News

**I want to know how the redirection done?
What is the function that did this redirection ?
How Does the website know where to go if the user clicks on "Contact Us" ?**

Comment: I bet the secret to this dilemma lies in the `index.php` file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't htaccess function, htaccess just parse "home-46-126", and redirect to index.php with these values.

If you want to work later with these values, you have to type it in PHP script.

```
<?php
$_GET["page"]; // including "home"
$_GET["id"]; // including "46"
$_GET["im"]; // including "126"
?>
```

Then you have to put these values to database or somethink, where you find out, that this ID and IM is page with Contact Us